# Tensor Products and Intersections

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two algebras $A$ and $B$, and two ideals $I, J \subseteq B$ with non-empty intersection, is it true that
$$
(A \otimes I) \cap (A \otimes J) = A \otimes (I \cap J)?
$$
(Where both sides of the equality are conatined in $A \otimes B$.) If so, then why?

Comment: I don't understand this.  Inside what set are $A\otimes I$ and $B\otimes J$ subsets?

Comment: There contained in $A \otimes B$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, it's fixed now.

Comment: $A \otimes I$ isn't going to be contained in $A \otimes B$ in general, unless you assume that $A$ is flat over the base of your tensor product (which you haven't given a name to). 

Comment: If "algebras" means "$k$-algebras" for a field $k$, then yes. More generally, if $A$ and $C$ are two $k$-vector subspaces of a $k$-vector space $U$, and if $B$ and $D$ are two $k$-vector subspaces of a $k$-vector space $V$, then $\left(A\otimes B\right)\cap \left(C\otimes D\right) = \left(A\cap C\right)\otimes \left(B\cap D\right)$. For a proof, consider bases of $A\cap C$, $A\diagup C$ and $C\diagup A$ and similarly for $B$ and $D$. On the other hand, if you are NOT over a field $k$, then your question doesn't even make sense: $A\otimes I$ is not (in general) a subset of $A\otimes B$.

Comment: And if $A$ <i>is</i> flat over the base ring, then it will preserve monos and pullbacks of pairs of monos = intersections. The algebra structure of $B$ doesn't really enter into this at all. 

Comment: @darij Yes I do mean an alg over a field, so thanks for answering my question. .... By basis do you mean Hamel basis?

Comment: Any kind of basis. I guess your algebras are finitely-dimensionally filtered or something like that; there is no reason to use AC in most applications.

Comment: Besides, you can always restrict yourself to finite-dimensional subspaces of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ instead of considering the whole $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ (remember, every tensor is a sum of finitely many pure tensors, and every pure tensor comes from one-dimensional subspaces), and again there is no need for Hamel bases.

Comment: @ Darij Ok, it seems there's no need for AC. One last thing though, by A/C I assume you mean a choice of complement in A/C.